# Rails returning results from other requests when connecting to multiple databases.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn, multiple-databases

On a server running nginx and unicorn, I have rails configured to connect to two different databases. Under even a light load, web requests to endpoints that access the second rails database will return results from other requests.

For example, if there are simultaneous calls to `http://example.com/user/111/address` and `http://example.com/user/222/address`, sometimes the address for user 222 will be returned for BOTH calls and sometimes it will return the address for user 111 on BOTH calls.

The enpoint for address is very basic.

```
class UserController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_user

  def address
    address = @user.address
    render json: address, status: 200 
  end 

  private 

  def load_user
    @user = User.find params[:id]
  end 
end
```

The models `User` and `Address` both access the second database and inherit from a base class that connects to that database:

```
class OtherDbActiveRecord < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_other_db"
  # Prevent creation of new records and modification to existing records
  def readonly?
    return true
  end

  # Prevent objects from being destroyed
  def before_destroy
    raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord
  end
end

class User < OtherDbActiveRecord
  has_one :address
end 

class Address < OtherDbActiveRecord
  belongs_to :user 
end
```

Is there a step to connect to a second db that I am missing? What could cause ActiveRecord to return the results for a different query?

Comment: i don't do rails, but maybe it's not the ruby code at all. do you possibly have proxy_cache enabled? could it be that the proxy_cache_key doesn't include the request path?

Answer (score 0):

OtherDbActiveRecord is a single object.  Each ruby class is an object, and it is a single object.  When you call establish_connection it sets the state of that (one) object to the given connection.

Try having duplicate classes each with distinct class names.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class UserOther < OtherDbActiveRecord
end

class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Address Other < OtherDbActiveRecord
end
```

Comment: The classes/tables for my main database are complete different from the other database.